# Array in JS - says it's object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm new to JS and I have a task to flatten an array. What I have is `[1,2,[3,4]]` and I have to turn it into `[1,2,3,4]`. I use the following approach

```
function flatten(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    });    
}
```

But it says `concat` is not a function.

```
Array.isArray(arr); //returns true
```

Can someone tell me what to do here :)

Comment: Hint: you are testing to see if `arr` is an array, but calling concat on `a`. Why don't you test to see if `a` is an array? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `arr` value is `[1,2,[3,4]]`. That's an array with three entries: the number `1`, the number `2`, and the array `[3,4]`.

The first two arguments to a `reduce` callback are

1. the *accumulator* (which is the return value of the previous invocation of the callback) and
2. a *value* taken in sequence from the array.

You don't supply an initial accumulator in your code, so that means the first call to the `reduce` callback accepts the first *two* entries as arguments (i.e., the first element of the array is used as an accumulator). `concat` is not a function because the initial value of `a` is a number, not an array. You tested to see if `arr` was an array, but did not test to see if `a` was an array.

The clear solution here is to supply an initial value to use as an accumulator:

```
function flatten(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    }, []);    
}
```

This creates an empty array (with `[]`) and then supplies it as the `a` value for the first call to the `reduce` callback.

Comment: So at the first step it will concatanate `[] + 1` and it will be `[1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to provide array `[]` after the callback function as initial value to `reduce`, otherwise that value will be first element of your array. So in your code in first iteration of reduce you are trying to do this `a.concat(b)` where `a` is 1 and `b` is 2 and that throws the error.

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  }, []);
}

console.log(flatten([1, 2, [3, 4]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```js
 var array = [].concat.apply([], [1,2,[3,4]]);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

DOCS about the array says

The JavaScript Array **object** is a global object that is used in the construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

In your example for reduce you will have to provide an initial value which can b an empty array.

```js
var flattened = [1,2,[3,4]].reduce(function(a, b) { 
  return a.concat(b);
}, []);

console.log(flattened)
```

Answer (score 1):

`concat` is expecting an Array of values to join with another Array. The reason this is failing is because your Array isn't a full matrix.

The problem with your array is that it wouldn't be wise to create a single hard coded solution for that specific Array, you should probably create a recursive function like:

```js
function flattenArr(arr) {
    const newArr = []

    function recursiveFlat(a) {

       if(!Array.isArray(a)) {
            newArr.push(a);
        }

        else {

            for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if(Array.isArray(a[i])) {
                    recursiveFlat(a[i]);
                }

                else {
                    newArr.push(a[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    arr.forEach(item => recursiveFlat(item));
    return newArr;

}

arr = [1, 2, [3, 4]]

console.log(flattenArr(arr))
```

That way it will always flatten the array no matter the shape.

Answer (score 0):

You just make sure that *arr* is an array. But,you call *concat* on a.
test this：

`if(a instanceof Array)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) combined with [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
var flattened = [].concat.call([], ...[1, 2, [3, 4]]);

console.log(flattened);
```